# Mobile web apps IDEs or frameworks focused on design?

Tags: android, ios, framework

I'm a bit lost on what kind of framework I should use to develop Android / iOS applications, I don't need the application to look native, I'm really focused on design, and the current frameworks focus on a "native look", for example there are these frameworks that I considered useful:

- [Sencha](https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/#overview)
- [Titanium](https://www.appcelerator.com/mobile-app-development-products/)
- [Monaca](https://monaca.io/)

Also I checked that many frameworks in turn can uses another, like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) (and so many others) uses [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), 
but I'm not sure if some of those will really help for this purposes.
What my application actually have to do is display a design structure like a mind map; 
a great example of what I need is **[this app called](http://www.mindlyapp.com/) [Mindly](http://www.mindlyapp.com/)**,
it has a very good example of functionality and fluid design effects.

[image: Mindly screenshot]

It's almost impossible to develop an app natively like that,
so, if someone could give a good recommendation to achieve this kind of designs would be useful for everyone.